# Can I somehow generate a memorable string from a string of random characters?

Tags: algorithm, encoding

Let's say I have a base64 encoded string. Can I somehow generate a memorable phrase from it to make it easy to memorise?

Comment: Definitely no, if encoded string is long enough.

Comment: Look at passphrase/seedphrase generators, e.g. [diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware) or https://www.eff.org/de/deeplinks/2016/07/new-wordlists-random-passphrases

Comment: How long is your string, and what are the 64 different characters used to encode it?